# Variable named the same as enumerator

Tags: c, enums, standards

What is the defined behavior for something like the following?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
  ENUM_VAL_1 = 1,
  ENUM_VAL_2 = 2
} TEST_ENUM;

int main() {
  TEST_ENUM testVar1 = ENUM_VAL_1;
  TEST_ENUM ENUM_VAL_1 = ENUM_VAL_1;
  TEST_ENUM testVar2 = ENUM_VAL_1;

  printf("ENUM_VAL_1 = %u\n",ENUM_VAL_1);
  printf("testVar1 = %u\n",testVar1);
  printf("testVar2 = %u\n",testVar2);

  return 0;
}
```

From my testing with both GCC and MSVC compilers, the behavior of this is that testVar1 will be set equal to the enumeration value "ENUM_VAL_1" or 1. However, the next statement will try to set the variable ENUM_VAL_1 equal to its own value, which is of course current uninitialized and thus garbage, instead of setting the variable ENUM_VAL_1 equal to the enumeration value ENUM_VAL_1. Then, of course, testVar2 will also get the same garbage value as the variable ENUM_VAL_1.

What is the defined behavior of this according to the C standards, or is this undefined behavior? Whether or not it is defined, I'm guessing this type of example is bad practice at very least due to the ambiguity.

Thanks!

Comment: You should update the title of the theme by substituting word enumeration for word enumerator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 4. ... If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity
>      (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other
>      entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the identifier
>      designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared
>      in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner
>      scope.**

And

> 7 Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just
>   after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
>   tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>   appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any
>   other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of
>   its declarator**

So in this declaration

```
TEST_ENUM ENUM_VAL_1 = ENUM_VAL_1;
```

declarator `ENUM_VAL_1` is considered completed before the sign =. So it hides the enumerator.

In fact it is initialized by itself and has an indeterminate value.

The same is valid for C++ (3.3.2 Point of declaration)

> 1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its
>   complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any),
>   except as noted below. [ Example:

```
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>   —end example ]

Answer (score 3):

I expected the `TEST_ENUM ENUM_VAL_1 = ENUM_VAL_1;` line to fail to compile, but it does.  I changed the assigned value to `ENUM_VAL_2`, and the printing then gives `ENUM_VAL_1 = 2`, `testVar1 = 1` and `testVar2 = 2`, so `ENUM_VAL_1` is a local variable.

It is actually a routine scoping issue; it means that the variable declaration in `main()` shadows the declaration outside — and if the `typedef` were within `main()`, the code would not compile.  Add `-Wshadow` to your compilation options to see the shadowing.  After setting `testVar1`, `ENUM_VAL_1` means the local variable, not the enumeration constant.  Initializing a variable with itself doesn't really initialize the variable; it copies undefined garbage into the value.